# How to fix binding issue in ListView

Tags: c#, mvvm, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.listview

Im trying to bind my ListView to an observableCollection on my ViewModel. The other bindings on the same class are working but i dont see any data where my list is supposed to be.

Ive tried setting the rows uneven, instantiating a separate Collection, and using breakpoints to confirm there is data.

Here is the xaml code:

```
<StackLayout Spacing="10" Padding="7" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0">
                <Label Text="Name:" FontSize="Medium"/>
                <Label Text="{Binding order.Name}" FontSize="Small"/>
                <Label Text="Price:" FontSize="Medium"/>
                <Label Text="{Binding order.Price}" FontSize="Small"/>
            </StackLayout>
            <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding order.foodItems}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" HasUnevenRows="True">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <StackLayout Padding="10" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="Fill">
                                <Label Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="Medium"/>                                
                                <Label Text="{Binding Quantity}" FontSize="Medium" />                                
                            </StackLayout>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

Here is my ViewModel

```
Order _order;
        public Order order 
        {
            get { return _order; }
            set { SetProperty<Order>(ref _order, value); }
        }

        public OrderDetailViewModel(Order value)
        {
            order = value;            
        }
```

The order class:

```
 public class Order
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<IFoodItems> foodItems;
        public double Price { get; set; }

        public Order(string name)
        {
            Name = name;
            foodItems = new ObservableCollection<IFoodItems>();
        }
        public void SetPrice(double value)
        {
            Price = value;            
        }
        public void AddItem(IFoodItems food)
        {
            foodItems.Add(food);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you please show full code of `foodItems` , it will be helpful.

Comment: Hey thanks for responding, i've updated the post @JuniorJiang-MSFT

Comment: Thanks for updating. Do you set like this: `public ObservableCollection<GatorStick> foodItems { get; set; }` in Order class. Or you can update code Order clsss.And in `GatorStick` class, `Name` property should have set method.`public string Name { get; set; }` I have posted an answer for testing custom data.

Comment: Hey i made these changes and the outcome is the same

Comment: Please show code of `Order` class.`GatorStick` and `OrderDetailViewModel`  should inherit from `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT I updated the post with the order code. Even though it's not on here both Gatorstick and OrderDetailViewModel inherit INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: According to the previous code, is `IFoodItems` the same as `GatorStick`? The ItemSource of the list view is the model data used.

Comment: Yes, that interface inherits ```INotifyPropertyChanged ```

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT Hey i think i found where the real problem is, is there a way to DM you? if not can i send you my project in an email?

Comment: Thanks for sharing your project.You can share a project link here ,so I will check it :) https://www.dropbox.com can upload project to share with other people.